# How can I make the LED initially off upon simulating the circuit?

Tags: arduino

The activity said: Create a program using the tactile switches that can make the Green LED light up in the first press, the Orange or Yellow LED in the second press, and Red in the third press. After three presses the switch should reset to the Green LED.

This is my code in Tinkercad. We're using C++ language.

```
int leds[3] = {4, 3, 2};
int button = 5;
int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
}
pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 int status = digitalRead(button);
 if(status == HIGH)
{
  delay(150);
  digitalWrite(leds[counter], LOW);
  counter++;

  if (counter > 3)
  {
    counter = 0;
  }
 }
 digitalWrite(leds[counter], HIGH);
}
```

The activity said that the green LED should turn on after pressing the button, but the green LED in my circuit is initially on as soon as I start simulating it. What should I do to make the LED initially off?

[This is my circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEPNl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We're using C language.

No this is not C but C++.

> What should I do to make the LED initially off?

Don't turn it on.

Befor the button has been pressed you turn on `leds[0]`.

You only have to change the leds status when the button is pressed.
But you turn the led on outside of that conditional statement.

#### Edit:

> can you tell me on which part of the code did I made that mistake?

You have two mistakes.

1. you turn the led on with `digitalWrite(leds[counter], HIGH);` everytime `loop` is executed. Move that function call inside the if statement so it will only be executed if the button is pressed. Otherwise the green led which is `leds[0]` will be turned befor you have pressed the button the first time. There is also no need to turn the leds on every call to loop. It is sufficient to do it once inside the conditional statement.
2. your counter reaches 3 befor you reset it to 0. But you only have 3 elements in your `leds` array. So the maximum index you can use is `2`

Replace

```
 counter++;

  if (counter > 3)
  {
    counter = 0;
  }
```

with
`counter = (counter + 1) % 3;`

Comment: thanks for correcting :) can you tell me on which part of the code did I made that mistake? I am new to arduino and I am so confused. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

That last line of code:

```
digitalWrite(leds[counter], HIGH);
```

When the loop first runs, `counter` is equal to zero. Arduino is zero-indexed, so when you call `digitalWrite(leds[counter], HIGH)`, you are setting the first LED to high.

---

You can set a "fake" pin.

```
int leds[4] = {8, 4, 3, 2};
```

Since you aren't using pin 8, it will have no effect.
Or, you could use pin 0 ***and*** use an if statement to skip that pin:

```
int leds[4] = {0, 4, 3, 2};
...
  if (counter > 0)
    digitalWrite(leds[counter], HIGH);
```

You would also need to change these lines:

```
  if (counter > 3)
  {
    counter = 1;
  }
```

Comment: 1) your code will cause a compiler error as your initialization list is too long for that array. 2) that "fake-pin" solution is nonsense. a) you don't mess with pins just because you don't use them atm, this will cause problems once your program grows. b) you don't workaround a broken logic, you fix it. so instead of adding unused pins to your list you rather make sure your index stays in the valid range